# $this not in object context for database connection base class

Tags: php, mysql, oop, this

I am trying to get this to work but it keeps giving me an error about $this not being in an object context for the line:

```
echo $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM enquiries") ;
```

Where am I going wrong? :(

```
class CoreModel {
protected $db ;

function __construct()
{
    try{
        $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", "user", "pass") ;
        $this->db->exec('set names utf8') ;
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, TRUE) ;
    }
    catch(PDOEXCEPTION $e)
    {
        echo $db->errorCode ;
        die() ;
    }
}

function test()
{
    echo $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM enquiries") ;
}

function __destruct()
{
    $this->db = NULL ;
}
}

echo CoreModel::test() ;
```

---

Thanks, I knew I was missing something obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `$this` if you don't create an instance of your CoreModel class. You can't call this function statically.

Create an instance using the `new` operator :

```
$db = new CoreModel();
$db->test();
```

Comment: It'd be nice if PHP didn't allow you to call non-static methods statically. It can only ever work if you are lucky, which is no way to design a language. I'm talking about PHP, so I don't know why I expected something different...

Comment: @siride - It would be nice if PHP did a lot of things that other languages did, but then it wouldn't be PHP.

Comment: @MystereMan not all languages are the same, but there are certain core concepts and practices that ought to be shared, and if they aren't shared, there should be a damn good reason for it.

Comment: `It'd be nice if PHP didn't allow you to call non-static methods statically` It does? Since when? Are you sure you're not confused.